# Update label text in uitableviewcell without reloading the entire table

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am building an application that lists all live and today (not live) matches in two different sections as:

```
section 0
live 1
live 2
section 1
today 1 (not live yet)
today 2
.....
```

Each table cell represents a match with two teams listed in it.  If it is a live match I have two labels(one corresponding to each team) which shows the live score.

For the live matches as there can a any number of live match in a particular sport category, I have two labels the show the score of each time at any given moment. As score in live match changes frequently so I have used socket to get data and I need to update the score labels of each match cell in their labels as the data arrives in socket through callback.

How can I get the label instance of each cell and update their text without reloading the entire table? Is there any way to maintain a reference of all labels as the cells are dynamic prototype?

How can I go about implementing this functionality? Please note that at any point of time a match may become live and shift from today to live and vice versa (if match gets cancelled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

`indexPaths` takes an array that contains the index paths of the rows that you want to reload, so e.g. if you want to reload only the first row in your first section call:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]
```

Comment: I needed to use the following to make it work: 
NSMutableArray *indexPathArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[indexPathArr addObject:indexPath];
And then call it like: 
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
and it worked like a charm in iOS 9.1 (8.0+), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Swift version

Go to the class where you have your tableView and do the following:

```
let singleIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [singleIndexPath], with: .none)
```